# How to convert a string in to a XML or how to parse a string on objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, string, tableview

i've got two important questions.

So we wanna build an App based on a Website with a login and so on.

After we typed in the loginname and password we send those things with POST. After that we get the website source code as an NSString.

I want this String to a local XMLFile so that I'm allowed to parse this xmlfile after saving.

Is it possible?

1. Question. After i parsed the XML File or String and i got my dates, i wanna put them in a TableView. But how?

Comment: Half the question is a possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840982/nsxmlparser-init-with-xml-in-nsstring-format, you don't need to save the NSString as a file to parse it, just do it in memory.

Comment: Like Jokke says, you can parse in memory. When you parse them out, store the dates in an array and use that array in a viewcontroller's datasource: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/tag/uitableviewdatasource/